# SQLAlchemy find rows between two dates, including the given end date

Tags: python, date, sqlalchemy

I want to find all rows between two dates, including the end date, but can only get rows with dates one day before the end date. So for example I have this entry:

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "taskDate": "Sat, 02 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT"
}
```

And I have this python SQLAlchemy code

```
tasks = Task.query\
        .filter(Task.task_date >= start_date)\
        .filter(Task.task_date <= end_date)\
        .all()
```

And if I create `end_date` from the date '2016-01-02' the row above is not returned. But if I use the date '2016-01-03' it is returned.

To me it should work since I use `task_date <= end_date` and that *should* include the given date, but it does not =(
I guess I could just add one day to all give end dates, but that seems wrong.

Am I missing something? If I set the start date to a specific date, that is including the one I give.

In my use case I'm only interested in dates, time (hours, minutes, seconds) are irrelevant. I just want the entries that are between two dates. All rows in the database have the normalized time of 00:00:00.

Comment: What is the database behind SQLA? Are you sure, that it's not a problem with time zones?

Comment: I found it, it was a problem with my normalization of the times, I had microseconds that weren't set to 0

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, my datetimes in the database was not normalized on microseconds, so the dates were microseconds too large.
Now I'm resetting all dates using this:

```
normalized_date = task_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Which makes the code in the question work